# Filtering by tag shows all pages instead of tagged pages

Tags: tags, wagtail

With reference to the Wagtial [recipe](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9.2/reference/pages/model_recipes.html) on tags, I have set up tags in my courses app. However, tag filtering does not seem to be working. The tags themselves seem to be working: I can select tags in the admin and show them on the page. I have a course page tag model that seems to be working properly:

```
class CoursePageTag(TaggedItemBase):
content_object = ParentalKey('CoursePage', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='course_tagged_items')
```

I have filtering setup in the  `CourseListingPage` model (with `template = "courses/course_listing_page.html"`) like this:

```
        #  Get all courses
    course_pages = (
        CoursePage.objects.live().public().order_by("-first_published_at")
    )
    # Filter by tag
    tag = request.GET.get('tag')
    if tag:
        course_pages = course_pages.filter(tags__name=tag)

    context['course_pages'] = course_pages
    return context
```

And in the template I have this:

```
    {% for tag in page.tags.all %}
    <a href="{% pageurl page.get_parent %}?tag={{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

When I click a tag on a course page with the above template code, I do arrive at the parent course listing page, and the URL shows what seems to be the correct filtering format:

```
courses/course-listing/?tag=test
```

But I do not see a filtered list of pages. Instead I see *all* course pages. I suspect there is something very simple that I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I can't immediately see anything wrong with the filtering logic, so my only thought is that the error is in the code we haven't seen, namely the template. Are you definitely using the `course_pages` variable there (as opposed to, say `{% for course in page.get_children %}`)? Failing that, standard debugging techniques apply... stick some `print` lines in the method so that we can see the values of `tag` and `course_pages` at the relevant points.

Comment: I am not using `course_pages` in the template. The snippet above is the entirety of the code for the tags on a given course page. The [docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9.2/reference/pages/model_recipes.html) indicate that this code should *show a list of tags associated with the page, with links back to the filtered index page.* The docs also say that this code should *filter the listing to only those pages with a matching tag name before passing this to the template for rendering.* Maybe I am misreading that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: {% for course in course_pages %} is required in the template at the location of the listing of the filtered pages -- in my case, below the filtering code. So, I now have the filtering code, then the actual listing of the pages, which begins with:

```
   {% for course in course_pages %}
   {% with course=course.specific %}

 ... HTML/template code for page details (e.g. course.title, course.sub_title) ...
      
    {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
```

I didn't initially that realize that the filtering code only does the filtering; it doesn't actually show the results of the filtering. For a beginner like me, when the docs say that the code will *filter the listing to only those pages with a matching tag name before passing this to the template for rendering*, it's possible to misread this to mean that the template will show the filtered results without further steps. But that's not the case. The extra contextual code is required -- at least it was for me.